# ubuntu 15.04 user experience with printer problems and suggestions for better printers

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint

I called Canon, and they don't seem to be interested in coming up with driver which could be used with Linux

The Canon MG3500 had everything I wanted, except the problems. Right now I don't print enough to justify buying a new printer. What really irks me is all troubleshooting issues are addressed through the installed software.

One thought I have is installing Wine, and setting up my computer using the Windos install disk.

Comment: I have had good results with HP and Brother printer/scanner combo devices with wifi. Both brands have very reasonable Linux support.

Answer (score 2):

### What Not to Do

Please don't point WINE to a Windows install.  See [How would one run windows applications in Linux that are already Installed in a Windows Environment?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296749/how-would-one-run-windows-applications-in-linux-that-are-already-installed-in-a), where I just answered that question.

### What You Should Do

1. Research before you buy. Visit the [Printer Listings Database
   Page](http://www.openprinting.org/printers).  Choose the Manufacturer, i.e. Cannon, and pick a Printer.
2. Click Show this Printer.
3. You want to choose a Printer that reads Works Perfectly, that has a driver listed.  For example, the Canon MultiPASS C5500 has the driver bjc600 listed, but only works *Partially*.
4. No matter the brand you choose, stay away from the ones listed as *Paperweight*.

Comment: I've never had a problem with any HP laser printers (although it's been a few years since I tried any new models, so things might have changed).  Pretty much anything else that speaks PCL and/or postscript should be fine too.

Comment: also, there are some things that inkjet printers are really good at (high-quality photos, for example) but if you only print infrequently (as I do), you'll often find that the ink has dried up and needs to be replaced.  and if you print frequently, the cost per page for laser printers is **much** lower.  lasers make excellent general purpose printers.  Inkjets are better for some special-purpose print jobs.  they're also a fantastic cash-cow for printer companies.