# How would one run windows applications in Linux that are already Installed in a Windows Environment?

Tags: windows, wine

There are two drives, one with a Windows installation, and one with a Linux installation. I would like to be able to run the applications already installed on the Windows environment from the Linux environment. More specifically, it would be nice to be able to capture registry values, user AppData, ProgramData, and other paths on the Windows drive. Is there a way to configure WINE to do something similar to that? And, if there isn't, is there a fork of WINE that does? If this information is needed, the two specific OS's are Windows 7 x64, and Mint 18.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short Answer

No, Don't try what you're asking, thinking or considering.

### Long Answer

Read the FAQ: [5.1 I have lots of applications already installed in Windows. How do I run them in Wine?](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#I_have_lots_of_applications_already_installed_in_Windows._How_do_I_run_them_in_Wine.3F), which states:

> Wine is not designed to interact with an existing Windows
>   installation. If you have any data you need from a Windows
>   installation, browse your Windows filesystems in your normal file
>   manager and copy the data to another location.

And then goes on to say:

> Do not try to configure Wine to point to your actual Windows C:\
>   drive. This will break Windows and require a Windows reinstall. We
>   have tried to make this hard to do, so you probably cannot do it by
>   accident. If you do manage this, Wine may or may not continue to
>   operate, but your Windows install will be 100% dead due to critical
>   parts of it being overwritten. The only way to fix Windows after this
>   has happened is to reinstall it.